# The article "the" before messages

Tags: articles

> He shouldn't have posted the PM's that were meant to be private. [PM = Private message]

Is the above sentence correct if we are talking about specific messages? Suppose that, on a forum that I am on, one poster sent 2-4 messages to another person in private, who then posted the screenshots of those messages. So wasn't I supposed to say he has "posted THE messages" (I have those 2-4 messages in my mind when I was talking about them there) instead of "posted messages"?

Is "the screenshots of those messages" or simply "screenshots of those messages" correct?

Answer (score 1):

> He shouldn't have posted PMs that were meant to be private.

The above means that, in general, he should not have posted PMs. Which PMs? We don't know. Posting PMs in general is bad.

> He shouldn't have posted *the* PMs that were meant to be private.

The above statement refers to some specific PMs he posted. Perhaps it was OK to post some of the PMs, but not others? At any rate, he should not have posted the PMs that he posted in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the meaning the poster wants to convey. *He shouldn't have posted PMs that were meant to be private* suggests that the only PMs involved were those that were meant to be private. *He shouldn't have posted the PMs that were meant to be private* suggests that there were other PMs that were not meant to be private.

In your question, *the screenshots of those messages* suggests that the screenshots somehow existed at the same time as the messages. *Screenshots of those messages*, with the zero article, avoids giving that impression.